# How do I print text from EditText to a textview when pressed enter or a button

Tags: java, android

So I want the text the person wrote in the EditText box to be printed on the screen when pressed enter or clicked on the button.

```
    final TextView txt= findViewById(R.id.empty_text);
    Button   btn =      findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    final EditText tst = findViewById(R.id.test_textEdit);


    final String value = tst.getText().toString();


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            txt.append(value+"\n");
            tst.setText("");
        }
    });
```

I think txt.append(value+"\n"); I think I need something that tells the computer to print the text but I  don't find one.

Comment: txt.setText(tst.getText().toString()) try this in your onClickListener

Answer (score 0):

`value` is only set once, and before you assign your `ClickListener`. Just pull whatever text is present inside your `EditText` every time `onClick()` is called.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        txt.setText(tst.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

**Edit:** I just realised you were looking to update the TextView on an "Enter" key press as well. For that you can try:

```
tst.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int id, KeyEvent event) {
        if (id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
            txt.setText(tst.getText().toString());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: https://gyazo.com/72c32fbdbe1b072159dddaeacbb804a5 You see the blue button is that like a enter button or go backwards button I own a iPhone. I just remembered there is no "enter" on phone but there are always a button that you can click to that works like "enter"

Comment: Yes, and you can customise its appearance and behaviour with IME Options on your `EditText`. It can signify "return", "done", "search" or many other things, which is why I'd suggest you use an `EditorActionListener` and not a Key Press Listener